# Yii ActiveRecord Simultaneous Update & Insert Fails without Errors

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2-advanced-app

I have a controller where I need to invalidate a token and create a new token.

The controller code snapshot looks something like this:

```
function __regenerate_token($t)
{
    if($token = Token::find()->where('token = :t' , ['t'=>$t])->one())
    {
        $token->expired = true;
        $token->save(); // ->save(false);
    }

    $newtoken = new Token();
    $newtoken->attributes = [
            'token'=> strtolower(trim(\com_create_guid(), '{}')),
            'expiry_at' => strtotime("+10 minutes"),
    ];
    $newtoken->save(false);

    return $newtoken;
}
```

Now whats happening is - update() also returns true & no errors. Same with insert. Individually run, they work fine. But if I call them they way it is - it fails silently.

The underlying table is innoDB. I tried to wrap the update & insert inside a transaction, but same issue.

Regard

Answer (score 0):

I found out the reason. I was calling __regenerate_token in a function after a db-transaction. However in certain condition, the execution exited the function before committing / rolling back the changes.  This caused the __regenerate_token also become part of the transaction and failed.

pseudo code

```
function debit_account
    begin transaction
    try
        do stuff
        if some_condition
           return false  #<-- this caused issue
        endif
        commit

        return true
    catch
        rollback

    return false
end function

debit_account()
__regenerate_token() #fails when some_condition is hit
```

Hope this someone else who hits a problem like this!